Running ollama on kaggle
I downloaded ollama on a kaggle notebook (linux). I want to interact with it using a python script. On following the instructions on the github repo and running: ollama run llama3 I got the output: Error: could not connect to ollama app, is it running?.
It appears that I need to run ollama serve before running llama3. However the entire main thread is taken up by ollama serve so you cannot run anything else after it.
The work arounds I tried:

Trying to create a background process: ollama serve & which returned OSError: Background processes not supported.
Trying to run it via python using subprocess.run('ollama', 'serve') which returns TypeError: bufsize must be an integer

Full logs of second method:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[29], line 1
----> 1 subprocess.run('ollama', 'serve')

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py:503, in run(input, capture_output, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    500     kwargs['stdout'] = PIPE
    501     kwargs['stderr'] = PIPE
--> 503 with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    504     try:
    505         stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py:780, in Popen.__init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, user, group, extra_groups, encoding, errors, text, umask, pipesize)
    778     bufsize = -1  # Restore default
    779 if not isinstance(bufsize, int):
--> 780     raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
    782 if pipesize is None:
    783     pipesize = -1  # Restore default

TypeError: bufsize must be an integer

I chose ollama because the setup was simple (just running a single command). I am ok with using another method besides ollama, however I want to run it on python without much setup as it is running on kaggle

maybe you should try to run it on local computer instead of Kaggle. Eventually you should check if it will work on Google Colab

This is what I did to get it to work:
#Download ollama
!curl -fsSL https://ollama.com/install.sh | sh
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen("ollama serve", shell=True) #runs on a different thread
#Download model
!ollama pull llama3
!pip install ollama
import ollama

#Then everytime you want to chat
response = ollama.chat(model='llama3', messages=[
  {
    'role': 'user',
    'content': 'Why is the sky blue?',
  },
])
print(response['message']['content'])

